# Load image from project folder in a html format to show in webcontrol

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webbrowser-control, windows

I have a windows application for a book. I show the chapter text in a webcontrol, because its in html format. In the chapter text there are some images which I added to a folder called Images. How can I load the specified image in a html tag?

```
chapterText += "<div align=center><img src=@'Images\\" + imageName + ".jpg' width='350' vspace='5'></div>";
```

I tried to add the images as resources but then I can not add them in the html code above.
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the image. If the images are stored locally, you are allowed to give a normal windows path:

[image]

One possible solution in your case would be to put the `Images` directory in your application folder and access it using the [Application.StartupPath property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.90%29.aspX), something like this:

```
// fetch directory where images reside, e.g.: c:\temp\app\images\
var imagePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Images");
// create image path, e.g.: c:\temp\app\images\one.jpg
var imageFile = Path.Combine(imagePath, String.Format("{0}.jpg", imageName));
// use it
chapterText += String.Format("<div align=center><img src='{0}' width='350' vspace='5'></div>", imageFile);
```

You have a couple of options to deliver the images with the executable:

- create an installer package that handles the dependies for you (e.g. MSI Setup package or ClickOnce)
- deliver an archive (ZIP containing the EXE and the images folder with the images)
- [embed the images into the EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), when the application is started, store them in a temp directory and retrieve them from there, when the application exits, delete the images from the temp directory
- embed the images into the EXE and then use them to embed them directly into to HTML using the [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

A solution for the last option could look like this:

```
var image = @"d:\temp\image.jpg";
// use MemoryStream to load the image from the embedded ressource
var imageAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(image));
var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
// embed the image directly into the html code, no need to load it from the file system
webBrowser.DocumentText = String.Format("<html><body><img src='data:image/jpg;base64,{0}' /></body></html>", imageAsBase64);
```

The output is same as the above image. This way you will not need the images directory anymore (or a temp one).

Comment: Thanks a lot Pasty, it works but only if i copied the Images folder in the bin\debug\Images. My concern now is it going to work the same when i finalize the project as an executable file book.exe

Comment: Glad, that the answer helped. I have extended my answer.